# Share Folder into shared folder

Tags: directory

I just have installed Ubuntu, and I make it my personal server at home.
I just got from Windows pc the server, I just saw the shared folders and I just share some documents into the folder, but I can't share an entire folder into other folder! What have to do to do this?
I'm rookie at ubuntu!
Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

**Here's how you can upload files or folders from Windows Machine to Ubuntu Server's Directory.**

- [Allow SSH](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-enable-ssh-on-ubuntu-18-04/) on your Ubuntu Server.
- [Create new user](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-and-delete-users-on-ubuntu-18-04) or allow existing user to access Ubuntu Server using SSH from your Windows Machine.
- Download FileZilla or any alternative software on your Windows Machine.
- SSH into the Ubuntu Server using FileZilla and upload files or folders into the desired directory.